# Is it possible to know that the error is CORS in Axios?

Tags: axios

Axios gives us the interception ability. I have created a response interceptor to get errors.

This is my code:

```
const errorInterceptor = error => {
  if (error.code === 'ERR_NETWORK') {
    throw new Error('Network is not connected')
  }
  // The rest of the code
}
```

However, if I get the CORS error, I can't find any information to know that it was a CORS error.

Why do I need this?

I want to provide meaningful messages to my users.

If network is disconnected, I want to show **You are not connected to the internet**. If it's CORS, I want to show **API is not configured properly for CORS, please inform the administrator**.

How can I know whether the error is CORS or not?

I have created an interceptor and I have tried to extract data from it.

Answer (score 0):

```
axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => response, (error) => {
  if (typeof error.response === 'undefined') {
    alert('A network error occurred. '
        + 'This could be a CORS issue or a dropped internet connection. '
        + 'It is not possible for us to know.')
  }
  return Promise.reject(error)
})
```